# i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException in Automation testing selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException error at following line  in both files Base file and HomePage file at following line code

**driver**.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
and 
**driver**.get("https://www.google.com");

Base class
public class Base {

```
    public WebDriver driver ;

    public WebDriver InitializeDriver() throws IOException
    {
        Properties Prop =new Properties();

        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Raj\\eclipse-workspace\\MavenSelenium\\src\\main\\java\\FirstMaven\\MavenSelenium\\Data.properties");

        Prop.load(fis);
        String browsername = Prop.getProperty("browser");

        if (browsername=="Chrome")
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Raj\\eclipse-workspace\\Work\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if (browsername=="Firefox")
        {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Raj\\eclipse-workspace\\Work\\geckodriver.exe");
           driver=new FirefoxDriver();  
        }
        else if(browsername=="IE")
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Raj\\eclipse-workspace\\Work\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
```

}

and HomePAge Class

public class HomePage extends Base{

```
@Test
public void Navigation() throws IOException
{

driver=InitializeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

}
```

}

Comment: Well if you compared strings correctly, then driver wouldn't be null.

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Your question can be answered very quickly and easily with your step-debugger. You should always try and solve your problems with a step debugger before coming to StackOverflow.

Comment: yes string compered correctly.  in debugger  it is throwing error at driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score -1):

A stacktrace is always helpful here but I was able to figure out what was wrong.

Based on the code you are getting a NPE because `driver` is never set. This is because `browsername=="Chrome"` should be `browsername.equals("Chrome")` or `"Chrome".equals(browsername)`.

`==` compares the reference of the object where as `.equals` compares equality.

Comment: Thanks but .equals  wont work in if condition

Comment: `if (browsername.equals("Chrome"))` most definitely does work in if conditions.

Comment: Thanks lot , i added it run as it is but issue is still there it is throwing error at driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: make sure you add it to all of your if statements. Also make sure your browser property matches completely (including case). It might be worth changing the if statement to `browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")`

Comment: If you are still having issues, please show me what the "browser" property is in your Data.properties file.

Comment: yes I did  it at all  and here is the properties file   data  : browser=Chrome  and  following error am getting

Comment: FAILED: Navigation
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SecMaven.Panda.Base.InitializeDriver(Base.java:41)
 at SecMaven.Panda.HomePage.Navigation(HomePage.java:12)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: In addition to using `.equals`, I would recommend adding an `else` block to the driver selection to see if the problem is not in configuration: `else { throw new RuntimeException("Configured driver not available: '" + browsername + "'"); }`